# How do I run a not trusted application in Windows 10 administrator account?

Tags: windows-10, permissions, user-accounts, administrator

I'm installing D-Link Dongle (Data card) for connecting to internet. But my Administrator account is not allowing to run this app.

It showed the message: "An administrator has blocked you from running this app..."

Program name: WirelessModem.exe
Publisher: Not trusted
...

Then I searched for solution on internet and installed it using in built Administrator account. No it is installed and can be run from that account (Hidden Admin account). But when I returned to my own Administrator account, it is still showing this error message. So I can't run the installed app. I have to run from Hidden Admin account every time.

Isn't there any way to make this application Trusted or Make it a trusted publisher? Or is there any other way to solve this problem?

Please help me resolve this problem. I shall be thankful to you.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 - The "This app has been blocked for your protection" message is different from "An administrator has blocked you from running this app.." one is a security feature the other is set by a domain policy.

Comment: @ramhound Good call...

Comment: Yup I installed using the way described on that link @Stackcraft_noob but it allows the app in that Hidden Administrator account only. When I run the app in my own user account, it shows the same message.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between a Hidden Administrator Account and normal Administrator account in Windows 10?](http://superuser.com/questions/1025169/whats-the-difference-between-a-hidden-administrator-account-and-normal-administ)

Answer (score 0):

To enable the Windows 10 administrator account do the following:

1. Press the Windows key.
2. Type `cmd` and wait for the results to be displayed.
3. Right-click no the *Command prompt* result and select *Run as administrator*.
4. If the User Account Control dialog box appears, confirm that the action it displays is what you want, and then click *Continue*.

Comment: But this runs the Dongle application in the Administrator account only. Isn't there any way to run in the normal user account as well?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem with the same D-Link app and tried all the suggested solutions with little success. However at some point I found that I could run the app "WirelessModem.exe" from the command prompt within the D-Link folder. I eventually created a Dongle.cmd file on the desktop with a single entry which pointed to "C:\Program Files (x86)\D-Link\WirelessModem.exe" .. yes quotes included

I then found I could right click and run the Donlge.cmd as Administrator and the app worked.... at some point I had also switched Windows Smartscreen filter Off so that may need to be done as well