# What's the difference between a Hidden Administrator Account and normal Administrator account in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-10, user-accounts, administrator

I'm asking this because my **D-Link Dongle** (datacard) app doesn't run in normal administrator account. It displays a message like: "An administrator has blocked you from running this app..."

So I activated the **Hidden Administrator account**. This can be done with:

```
net user administrator /active:yes
```

Here, the app runs. But it doesn't run in the normal Administrator account. So I'm thinking to use the Hidden Account as permanently. Would there be any lack of functionality in this account?

If possible, please help me run this app in both accounts. Here's the error I'm getting:

[image]

Comment: What do you consider to be a "normal" Administrator account precisely?

Comment: When you install Windows 10, the first account you login is the normal Administrator account i.e., it has administrator privileges.

Comment: I think he means regular account with administrator rights

Comment: Why are you running setup multiple times? You should only have to run it once (and maybe select "install for all users").

Comment: @DavidPostill installation isn't required. It is already installed. It's only the app that is not running.

Comment: @VikasKumar And the app is called "setup"? That's a bit strange.

Comment: Normally "setup" would install the app and leave a shortcut that then runs the actual application ...

Comment: You're the sage and I'm the disciple @DavidPostill I know very less. But the app is not running. Help if you can, please.

Comment: Well I don't have the program (or Windows 10) so I can't hand hold you through installing it properly.

Comment: @VikasKumar - So you mean a user account in the Administrator group vs the disabled by default built-in Administrator user.

Comment: Note that this is a duplicate of [How do I run a not trusted application in Windows 10 administrator account?](http://superuser.com/q/1020177). Please read [What should I do if no one answers my question?](http://superuser.com/help/no-one-answers)

Answer (score 4):

#### What's the difference between a Hidden Administrator Account and a normal Administrator account?

> **One master account to rule them all**
>
> Most operating systems have some sort of special-purpose master
>   account: one that lets you control the OS with virtually no
>   restrictions. This type of account has various names: “superuser,”
>   “root,” “supervisor,” and so forth. Windows calls it Administrator.
>
> Windows’ master account doesn’t simply enhance a standard admin-level
>   user account or serve as an elevated version of the Run as
>   administrator option. Administrator operates much like a normal user
>   account, except it has virtually unlimited permissions.
>
> Once activated, Administrator (or Admin for short) is a separate
>   account, complete with its own private desktop and user files. You can
>   set it up with its own themes, background, and other customizations,
>   and you can install software that’s not shared with non-admin-level
>   users.
>
> The unfettered, full-permission access offered by the Administrator
>   account is ideal when you need access to the deepest parts of Windows
>   — for example, when you’re trying to resolve really thorny system
>   problems. But clearly, that level of control can also be dangerous.
>   There’s no safety net, so a misstep could royally screw up your
>   system.
>
> That’s why Microsoft hides the Admin account by default. It’s not
>   intended for full-time, routine use — the risks are simply too great —
>   but it’s there for knowledgeable users to employ when needed.
>
> **A review of Windows’ admin-level access options**
>
> As noted, Windows offers three ways to access admin-level permissions
>   and functions. They are, from simplest to most powerful:
>
> - **Run as administrator**: This option is typically used to temporarily access limited admin-level rights from within a
>     non-admin-level (standard) account. In some cases, tasks that require
>     administrator-level permissions can be run by simply right-clicking
>     the name of an app or function and selecting the “Run as
>     administrator” option.
>
>   The process has a couple of speed bumps: a user account control (UAC)
>     prompt must be acknowledged, and you must also enter an admin-level
>     password. This two-step process can cause problems with complex and
>     multi-step admin-level tasks. Also, depending on the account type
>     (standard, guest, or child), some admin-level tasks are simply
>     off-limits.
> - **Assign a user account as an administrator**: Admin-level user accounts are subject to UAC controls. A warning will pop up whenever a
>     potentially dangerous system change is about to start — for example,
>     when installing new software or making system-level changes that might
>     affect other users. The task won’t proceed until the user explicitly
>     grants permission via a UAC prompt.
>
>   This one-step speed bump lets most admin-level tasks run to
>     completion. However, some complex, multi-step tasks might fail. This
>     can happen when a task requires several admin-level tools working in
>     series or uses command lines or scripts. The process could stop
>     because only the first tool or task received the necessary
>     permissions.
> - **Sign in as Administrator**: The master Admin account — the focus of this article — has full permissions and operates with virtually no
>     restrictions. It has none of the restrictions or drawbacks of the
>     first two administrator-access methods.
>
>   When you’re in the Admin account, you’ll likely never see a UAC
>     prompt — any system-level task you initiate is carried out
>     immediately. Not only is this UAC-free operation convenient, it will
>     also let you complete complex tasks that would otherwise fail. Within
>     an Admin account, you can sequentially run multiple tools and tasks
>     without the problem of repeatedly confirming elevated privileges.

Source [Activate Windows’ hidden, master admin account](http://windowssecrets.com/top-story/activate-windows-hidden-master-admin-account/)

Comment: But when I search for Control Panel or Calculator or some inbuilt apps in this account, they're not listed in search. Why is so?

Comment: I've no idea :/

Comment: Ok. Can you tell how to run a .exe file through cmd? This is the path of file I want to run: C:\Program Files (x86)\D-Link Connection Manager\WirelessModem.exe

Comment: [How to run Control Panel tools by typing a command](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/192806) or type `control` for the control panel, `calc` for calculator.

Comment: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\D-Link Connection Manager\WirelessModem.exe"` should work. You need quotes as the are spaces in the path.

Comment: Easier is to create a short cut to the program (which is what `setup` should have done in the first place).

Comment: It's not working @david

Comment: I wrote in cmd: start ".........................." and hit enter. Another cmd window opened.

Comment: Don't type `start`, it's not necessary.

Comment: Still it's not opening. I tried to open a normal text file, even that didn't open.

Comment: @VikasKumar - Post an answer of what exactly worked, because I don't see an answer, suggesting anything that would "make it work"

Comment: @Ramhound I'm about to give up. Unfortunately the OP is lacking basic knowledge - see his newer  question [How do I run an app/file using cmd in Windows 10?](http://superuser.com/q/1025192)

Comment: @DavidPostill it worked the way you told.