# How do I run an app/file using cmd in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

This is the path of the file I want to open:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\D-Link Connection Manager\a.txt
```

All control panel apps opens using start command, but this one is not opening. What's the problem?

Comment: I want to run a.txt file using CMD.

Comment: OK, so you need to use quotes like this: "C:\Program Files (x86)\D-Link Connection Manager\a.txt" This is because of blanks in the path ...

Comment: Yes, it's working. I found the similar answer somewhere else. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any solution to this problem? (Read the detail in the end, main problem lies in there) http://superuser.com/questions/1025169/whats-the-difference-between-a-hidden-administrator-account-and-normal-administ/1025174?noredirect=1#comment1426744_1025174

Comment: Seems to be not related to current question?

Comment: Hmm. You said as the last comment to my answer "It's working. Thank you". Is it working or not working? In any case your comments are not related to your original question (which I answered).

Comment: Why are you trying to run `a.txt`? You said you were having problems running `C:\Program Files (x86)\D-Link Connection Manager\WirelessModem.exe`

Comment: `C:\Program Files (x86)\D-Link Connection Manager\a.txt` is not a control panel command.

Comment: Try running `notepad "C:\Program Files (x86)\D-Link Connection Manager\a.txt"`

Comment: If you insist on using `start` (which I already told you you don't need) then you need to use the correct syntax `START "title" [/D path] [options] "command" [parameters]`. See [start](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) - Start a program, command or batch script (opens in a new window). If the command is quoted `"command with spaces"` you **must** have a title, even if it is an empty string `""`.

Answer (score 0):

If your path has blanks, you need to use quotes like this: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\D-Link Connection Manager\a.txt"`

Comment: Since when were spaces called blanks?